# Where can I find information on corporate bonds (especially those rated as "junk") ?

Tags: bonds, junk-bonds

I've been searching a number of financial sites and I can't seem to find a way to browse for companies that are selling bonds, and what rates/durations those bonds are at. How does one go about finding this kind of information? Ideally I'd like an interface that's as intuitive to use as a stock ticker. Specifically I'm looking for junk bonds. It could be I'm just using bad google queries...

Answer (score 1):

Bond information is much tougher to get.  Try to find access to a Bloomberg terminal.  Maybe you have a broker that can do the research for you, maybe your local university has one in their business school, maybe you know someone that works for a bank/financial institution or some other type of news outlet.

Part of the reason for the difference in ease of access to information is that bond markets are dominated by institutional investors.  A $100 million bond issues might be 90% owned by 10-20 investors (banks, insurance co's, mutual funds, etc.) that will hold the bonds to maturity and the bonds might trade a few times a month/year.  On the other hand a similar equity offering may have several hundred or thousand owners with daily trading, especially if it's included in an active stock index.

That being said, you can get some information on Fidelity's website if you have an account, but I think their junk data is limited.  Good luck with the hunt.

Answer (score 0):

You can get junk bond information on any brokerage site (particularly if you have a brokerage account), such as Etrade, and look for bonds that have junk level credit ratings.  Investment grade is S&P: rated BBB- or above, or Moody's: rated Baa3 or above.  Below that is considered junk.

Just go to the bond desk , e.g, on Etrade:  Trading-->bonds--> (see below)

[image: the etrade 'find bonds' screen]

You can see how it asks you to search by various fields